# Cancelling and creating tasks from different requests

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

In an ASP.net core application I spawn background tasks in one request, which can finish by themselves, or be cancelled by a second request. I have the following implementation, but I feel there should be a better way of achieving what I want? Does somebody have some experience with this problem?

```
public sealed class SomeService
{
    private record BackgroundTask(Task Task,
        CancellationTokenSource CancellationTokenSource);

    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, BackgroundTask> _backgroundTasks
        = new();

    public void Start(Guid id)
    {
        var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

        var cancellationToken = cancellationTokenSource.Token;

        var task = Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            try
            {
                await Task.Delay(1000, cancellationToken);
            }
            finally
            {
                _backgroundTasks.TryRemove(id, out _);
            }
        }, cancellationToken);

        _backgroundTasks.TryAdd(id, new BackgroundTask(task, cancellationTokenSource));
    }

    public void Cancel(Guid id)
    {
        _backgroundTasks.TryGetValue(id, out var backgroundTask);

        if (backgroundTask == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        
        backgroundTask.CancellationTokenSource.Cancel();

        try
        {
            backgroundTask.Task.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException e)
        {
            // todo: cancellation successful...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How important are these tasks for the health of your application? If they are even mildly important, you should be aware that there is no guarantee about their completion. Take a look at this: [Fire and Forget on ASP.NET](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/fire-and-forget-on-asp-net.html)

Comment: Also, as soon as you try to scale out, this will break very quickly.

Comment: Why do `TryAdd` and `TryGetValue` and, in both cases, ignore the return `bool`? Your code would be more robust if you used the return values. They're there for a reason.

Comment: Thank you for the link, it was very informative. Scalability will not be an issue, but the tasks are important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a race condition in the code below:

```
var task = Task.Run(async () =>
{
    try
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000, cancellationToken);
    }
    finally
    {
        _backgroundTasks.TryRemove(id, out _);
    }
}, cancellationToken);

_backgroundTasks.TryAdd(id, new BackgroundTask(task, cancellationTokenSource));
```

It is theoretically possible that the `task` will be added in the `_backgroundTasks` after its completion, and so it will never be removed from the dictionary.

One solution to this problem could be to create a cold `Task`, and `Start` it only after it has been added in the dictionary. You can see an example of this technique [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54117652/concurrentdictionary-getoradd-async/65694270#65694270). Working with cold tasks is a low level and tricky technique, so be cautious!

Another solution could be to not use a dictionary at all, and identify the `BackgroundTask`s by reference instead of by id. You don't need to expose the internal `BackgroundTask` type. You can return an `object` reference of it, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71369276/how-to-lock-threads-only-if-they-have-to-work-on-non-overlapping-rows-of-the-dat/71375831#71375831) for example. But I guess that you have some reason to store the `BackgroundTask`s in a collection, so that you can keep track of them.